# Hottest period in the history of the universe

Tags: cosmology, temperature, cosmological-inflation

Stack exchange's tagline is 'hot questions' - so here is one that will hopefully cause some heated debate.

I remember hearing that the period immediately after inflation is theorized to be the hottest - even hotter than the period before inflation - due to the collapse of the inflation field. Is this so, or flat-out wrong?

Comment: do you mean *energy density* or *total energy* ? likely the first since you use *hot* further ...You are asking about speculative theories and there are many , particularly on inflation and its articulation with the expansion

Answer (score 3):

There is a limited sense in which this correct. When inflation ended there was a temperature rise known as [reheating](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2600), and we believe it was at this stage that the standard model particles were first created, or at least the majority of them. If you are measuring temperature by the energies of the standard model particles then this would have been the hottest moment.

However the energy density was obviously higher at earlier times and therefore it seems reasonable to claim the temperature was higher. It depends on how you want to define temperature. Too little is known about what was going on in and before the inflationary era for us to say anything more concrete.